# Using f# to mimic linux touch command, need help implementing

Tags: f#, touch, f#-interactive

I am trying to write a f# program which mimics the touch command in linux, it checks a file paths exists if it does time stamp is updated, if it doesnt exist file is created. How do i implement this correctly?

I've tried using .net functions which i think essentially do the functions i need. I am working with file.exists, file.create and file.setlastaccesstime

// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

````
open System.IO

type Filepath = string


   let touch = 

    let checkExists filePath =
    if File.Exists filePath
    then Result.Ok (filePath:Filepath)
    else Result.Error "File does not exist"
     let path = Console.ReadLine()

     let update =
     path = Console.ReadLine()
     if File.Exists(path)
     File.Create(path)
     else File.SetLastAccessTime(path, DateTime.Now)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Touch command for windows"
    -> touch()
    -> update()

    0 // return an integer exit code```
````

Comment: What is the problem with your current implementation?

Comment: I receive error codes stating the update value is not defined, and also for the update method that let can not be the final code element in a block.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has several problems. I'll try to go through them one by one.

First, the indentation of the code in your question is totally messed up. If this is a direct copy and paste from your code, the first thing we need to do is fix the indentation: in F#, indentation is significant, and determines code blocks. (If your question's indentation is messed up because you fiddled with the indentation in the Stack Overflow question editor and your actual code indentation is fine, then consider this a refresher on how F# indentation works).

In F#, these two code blocks do something different:

```
if value = 5 then
    printfn "Five"
printfn "Value: %d" value
```

This will always print "Value: 3" or "Value: 27" or whatever, and will also print the word "Five" if the value is exactly 5. But this next code block does something else:

```
if value = 5 then
    printfn "Five"
    printfn "Value: %d" value
```

This will either print nothing at all, or it will print the word "Five" followed on the next line by "Value: 5". That's because the second `printfn` function call is indented at the same level as the first one, meaning it's part of the `if` block.

Also, a `let` statement needs to be followed either by a value on the same line, or by an indented block:

```
let value = 5

let otherValue =
    if value < 5 then
        5
    else
        3
```

After this is executed, the value of `otherValue` will be 3. Also, the code block under `let otherValue =` will only be executed **once**. That's because `otherValue` is not a function, it's a value. If you wanted `otherValue` to be a function, you would need to give it parameters:

```
let calculateValue inputValue =
    if inputValue < 5 then
        5
    else
        3
```

And now you can call that function like:

```
let value = 5
let otherValue = calculateValue value
// Now otherValue is equal to 3
```

This brings us to the second problem your code has, which is that you clearly intend `touch` and `update` to be functions, but you didn't give them parameters. Which means that they're *values* which are only executed once. You need to turn `let touch =` into `let touch () =` to make `touch` a function instead of a value, and same for `update`.

Another problem you have is more of a design issue: your `update` function is doing two things. It's reading a value from the console, and it's taking actions based on that value. It's much better design to have each function do only one thing: let your `update` function take `path` as a parameter, and then elsewhere you can have the code that reads `path` from the console and calls `update path`. This makes it much easier to write unit tests that test the `update` function, because instead of having to somehow figure out how to hook up your unit tests to stdin, you can just have your tests call your `update` function.

Another issue that Guran pointed out in a comment (thanks!) is that your `update` function has the logic backwards. You wrote "if file exists, create file, else set last access time". It should be the other way around. I missed this in the first version of this answer, so I've updated my fixed code below to correct the order of the `if...then...else` block in `update`.

Another issue I see is: what is your `touch` function (currently it's a value, but you clearly intended it to be a function) supposed to be doing? The only thing inside your `let touch =` block is other function definitions; the `touch` code block never actually calls the functions it defines. Which means it's useless: by having those function definitions *inside* the `touch` code block, you're hiding them from any code outside the `touch` code block, yet the `touch` code block never calls them. Functions defined at the top level of a module are visible to any code that can access the module. Functions (and variables) defined inside a code block are visible only in the scope of that code block. This is useful for encapsulating things that shouldn't be visible to the outside world, e.g. in the following example:

```
let counter() =
    let mutable value = 0
    let update() =
        value <- value + 1
        value
    update
```

Here, the `value` variable inside `counter()` is *not accessible* to the rest of the world. Also, notice how I've written `update` with no parentheses as the last line of the `let counter() =` code block: that means that the function named `update` will be the return value of `counter()`. In other words, when you call `counter()`, you get a function that, each time you call it, will return a new value that is the previous value plus 1. But two different counters are separate from each other:

```
let a = counter()
let b = counter()
let a1 = a()
let b1 = b()
let a2 = a()
let b2 = b()
printfn "A1: %d" a1
printfn "A2: %d" a2
printfn "B1: %d" b1
printfn "B2: %d" b2
```

This will print "A1: 1", "A2: 2", "B1: 1", and then "B2: 2". Now as an exercise, what would happen if I replaced `let counter() =` with `let counter =` in the above code? (I would also have to change `let a = counter()` to `let a = counter`, and same for `let b = ...`). Try to guess what would happen, then try it and see if you were right. (Hint: values, unlike functions, are only executed *once*).

And one final thing: the arrows in your `main` function are not correct. That's not what the `->` operator is for. If you need to call several functions in a row, just write the function calls one after the other.

Okay, that's as much as I can do right now to help you fix your code's problems. There are more issues (it would be better to get your paths from `argv` rather than from `Console.ReadLine()`, for example) but those can wait until you have a bit more F# experience under your belt. Here's your code with just the fixes I've mentioned so far. Oh, and one more fix: I'm deleting the `let touch =` line since I can't tell what you intended to put in your `touch` function. So here's your code, somewhat fixed but still in need of more fixes:

```
open System.IO

type Filepath = string

// NOTE: This function is unused. Why do you have it?
let checkExists filePath =
    if File.Exists filePath
    then Result.Ok (filePath:Filepath)
    else Result.Error "File does not exist"

let update path =
    // Note: the "then" and "else" blocks are swapped from your original code
    if File.Exists(path)
    then File.SetLastAccessTime(path, DateTime.Now)
    else File.Create(path)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "Touch command for windows"
    let path = Console.ReadLine()
    update path

    0 // return an integer exit code
```